# get text/html value of selected mat-option mat-select in angular 6, angular material 2

Tags: angular-material2, angular6

Whats the most efficient way to get text/html of selected option in mat-select that is part of a form or not a form?

I am really stuck on how to go about it.

```
     <mat-form-field class="w-100">
                 <mat-select class="w-100" placeholder="{{'Activities.haveEducation' | translate}}" formControlName="edu">
                     <mat-option value="1">{{'Shared.yes' | translate}}</mat-option>
                     <mat-option value="0">{{'Shared.no' | translate}}</mat-option>

                </mat-select>                
                </mat-form-field>
```

and the same when there is no form. I need to get the Yes/No instead of 1 or 0 of the selected ooption

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `viewValue` property of the selected option:

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <mat-select #select class="w-100" placeholder="{{'Activities.haveEducation' | translate}}" formControlName="edu">
        <mat-option value="1">{{'Shared.yes' | translate}}</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="0">{{'Shared.no' | translate}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>                
</mat-form-field>

<div>
    Selected: {{ select.selected?.viewValue }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is unfriendly to the user and if i have 10 select elements, i will create 10 div's ust for that. Guess its time to return to bootstrap instead. Thanks still for your help.

Comment: There's nothing forcing you to use 10 divs - I'm just showing you an example. Explain what you want to accomplish. It sounds like you are new to Angular and don't really understand how things work.

Comment: really helpful, saved my  day